# Sample dataset: files of a typical company

Tags: data-request, business

I am building a sync [app](http://cmissync.com) for enterprise users, and would like to test it with a large collection of real-world business files. Typically the kind of files you would find in a company's [file server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management). It would also be useful when performing demos.

Since every company is different, I would like a sample dataset containing a representative range of files:

- Invoices
- Contracts
- Requests for proposal, commercial proposals
- Marketing material and branding design files
- Internal memos
- Generated reports
- Scanned documents
- Accounting files
- Software installers and licences
- Documentation for company tools
- Events pictures
- etc

Possibly also some domain files like product design documents, CAD files, etc.

It MUST be under an open license.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are too many diverse filetypes to expect a good set. For example, wikipedia has many listed at [List of File Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats), with this disclaimer:

> This is an [incomplete list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Lists#Incomplete_lists) that may never be able to satisfy particular standards for completeness.

But, if you make a list of possible extensions (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_%28alphabetical%29) from a list of lists, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_list_of_filename_extensions_(A%E2%80%93E)) for A-E), you can pass them all in a big loop to a search engine with a "filetype:abc" argument (and download the results).

The problem is that I don't know of a search engine that has robust filetype searching. I checked both Google and DuckDuckGo and neither found actual files for the few I checked.

So, this isn't really an answer, but perhaps someone knows a search engine for robust filetype searching. Hopefully that search engine also has a way to filter based on license.

Comment: "*too many diverse filetypes to expect a good set*": No, the set of files of pretty much any company would be a good set already. I am not looking for every file type ever created, just an example of what the company next door is using :-)